# Intersection of all prime ideals of weakly Noetherian ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, noetherian

> Prove that intersection of all prime ideals is nilpotent in weakly Noetherian associative ring R.

Hello,

I've got stuck with this question. Could you please give any advice or reference to some books where i can found information about weakly noetherian associative rings.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It would be nice if you could remind us what's a weakly noetherian ring.

Comment: Any two-sided ideal is finitely generated

Comment: It's a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2486478/29335, but unfortunately that one does not yet have an answer either.